# OSError caffe2_detectron_ops_gpu PyTorch

Tags: dependencies, pytorch, oserror

I keep getting this error when i try to run my code with PyTorch

> OSError: [WinError 126] The specified module could not be found. Error loading “C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\torch\lib\caffe2_detectron_ops_gpu.dll” or one of its dependencies.

I tried updating form cuda 10.1 to 10.2 but it didnt fix the issue. i also have cudnn installed . I uninstalled and reinstalled torch multiple times with the commands found on the get started page of PyTorch. Can someone help me resolve this i’ve being stuck for 2 days now

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved cudnn64_7.dll was missing from system32 folder

Comment: Hi, i have the same problem could you explain your solution pls?